# Which part of speech is "row" in this sentence?

Tags: word-usage, headlinese

I read a headline in "The Hindu" which was:

> India, Pakistan row over Hindu sisters' abduction

Has "row" been used as a verb here? I think so because if it had been a noun here then there had been a hyphen in between India and Pakistan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The grammar here can't be approached by normal rules, because it is a headline. Those take liberties with grammar to save space. Thus "India, Pakistan" means "India and Pakistan".

***Row*** takes its [verb meaning as argue, particularly a loud argument](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/row). This is pronounced differently from what you do with oars to make a boat move, rhyming with *cow*, not with *so*. Of course, this being headline language, it could also be the noun meaning with the same pronunciation and sense - the meaning is the same.

Thus, it is saying that **India and Pakistan** are **arguing** (or have argued, or had an argument) about **the abduction of Hindu sisters**.